# How can I parse and display all the rostopics and messages published by a rosbag (C++)

Tags: c++, parsing, ros

I have a rosbag, that constantly publishes messages under certain topics. I want to write a function, that will take in the "rostopic" as the input argument and display the messages published by that topic.

How do I go about coding this. I am unable to find relevant examples. Can you please point to relevant  sources?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you elaborate more, the trivial answer is [rostopic](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic)

```
$ rostopic echo -b log_file.bag /topic_name
```

and you can take a look at it's source code [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/kinetic-devel/tools/rostopic/src/rostopic/__init__.py).

Cheers,